# Как получить одно и тоже случайное число при одинаково заданных начальных условиях?

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно использовать генератор случайных чисел который при заданном начальном условии  генерировал одно и тоже число.

Например сервер получает идентификатор группы `group_id` продуктов,  на основе этого числа генерируется, случайный код, все продукты имеющие одинаковые `group_id` должны получить одинаковый  случайный код.

Есть ли возможность сделать это без php `srand()`, как можно это сделать с 
помощью javasript ?

Сохранить первый полученный код для продукта и использовать его для всех остальных , или другие способы не приемлемы (в связи с конструкцией кода и поставленной задачей).

Comment: Генератор случайных чисел генерировал одно и то же число????)))  да легко...  `var nam = "Число" ` и даже генератор случайных чисел не нужен

Comment: На вопрос был дан исчерпывающий ответ в русле рекомендованных практик. Вопрос как сделать без srand - является новым отдельным вопросом (жутко велосипедным, костыльным и я уверен, что такие задачи точно не стоит тащить в продакшн - и я например буду спрашивать, зачем нужны такие костыли когда есть правильное решение и пока не будет прояснён бизнес-смысл - буду считать, что задан некачественный вопрос), задавайте его отдельно, а этот вопрос не стоит переделывать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию `srand()` для указания начального числа ГСЧ.
Тогда генерация через `rand()` будет всегда начинаться с одного и того же значения.